# How to display most viewed posts without any plugins

Tags: pagination

I'm working on a WordPress site that is only in staging mode at the moment and I want to be able to display the most viewed posts in a template. I have some code that is working, but with a little problem. When I click to the next page it is showing the same 10 results as the first page. Also, how can I change the results to show a 24 hour period, week, month and so on? This is the code I used:

In the functions.php:

```
function getPostViews( $postID ) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, true );
    if ( $count=='' ) {
        delete_post_meta( $postID, $count_key );
        add_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, '0' );
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views'; 
} 
function setPostViews( $postID ) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, true );
    if( $count == '' ) {
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta( $postID, $count_key );
        add_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, '0' );
    } else {
        $count++;
        update_post_meta( $postID, $count_key, $count );
    } 
}
// Remove issues with prefetching adding extra views remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

In the single.php loop:

```
setPostViews( get_the_ID() );
```

In the template:

```
query_posts( 'meta_key=post_views_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC' );
```

I'm also displaying the total views with this, but I might yet drop this part:

```
echo getPostViews( get_the_ID() );
```

What have I done wrong for the pagination to keep displaying the same 10 results?

On a second question, I'm using GD Star Rating plugin and would like to be able to do the same with it, but I don't know where to start. Hopefully someone here can help me out. I have looked at several other voting and rating plugins but this is the only one that can be used with myCRED plugin.

Comment: This subject has been handled before. I know I did post something on this before. Please use the site search, you should come up with a couple ideas. If you don't succeed, please update your question via an [edit]. Thank you :-)

Comment: Don't use query_posts, it will cause problems (like breaking pagination). Use WP_Query or get_posts instead.

Comment: @Gabriel I have changed the template to show
`code`<? 
get_posts ('meta_key=post_views_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC'); 
?>`code`
and now no posts are visible. Did I screw up somewhere? I'm relatively new to fiddling with templates, but willing to learn

Comment: Use `WP_Query` if you need to paginate a query. `get_posts` is a monster to paginate :-).  Anyway, this issue has being handled a thousand times with very good explanations and examples. Just use the site search. As for changing the code above to your needs, that is going to need some serious coding and a total rewrite. You will need to store values separate from the ones in the code above and then update that values on a daily, weekly or monthly basis depending on your needs.